# get all record between two dates interval in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, redmine

get all record between two dates interval in mysql

I have a user and resource_bookings tables in redmine. I want to get record of users who works 8 hours, less than 8 hours,
0 hours and more than 8 hours work between two given dates on basis of date period.

User table:

```
id  firstname   lastname    status  type
1   Ankur       Mishra      1       user
2   Anil        Chauhan     1       user
3   Jitendra    Singh       1       user
....
```

resource_bookings table:

```
id  project_id  user_id   start_date                end_date              hours_per_day
1   363         3         2019-09-13 00:00:00       2019-10-31 00:00:00   4 
2   350         3         2019-09-01 00:00:00       2019-11-30 00:00:00   6 
3   316         260       2020-01-01 00:00:00       2020-02-31 00:00:00   8.5 
....
```

My expected output is:

When user select start date '2019-08-01' and end date '2020-02-01', expected out is like this:

```
id  user_id   user_name       start_date       end_date     hours_per_day
1   1         Ankur Mishra    2019-08-01       2020-02-01   0 
2   2         Anil Chauhan    2019-08-01       2020-02-01   0 
3   3         Jitendra Singh  2019-08-01       2019-08-31   0
4   3         Jitendra Singh  2019-09-01       2019-09-12   6
5   3         Jitendra Singh  2019-09-13       2019-10-31   10
6   3         Jitendra Singh  2019-11-01       2019-11-30   6
7   3         Jitendra Singh  2019-12-01       2020-02-01   0
....
```

Please note in above expected output, we need all date intervals from starting date to end date even if the user is unscheduled for any slot/period. And If two slot period overlap we need sum of those slots in output.

Comment: How to deal with a partial match, e.g. a row starting '2019-07-01' and ending '2019-08-05'. This is partly inside the period and partly outside. Do you want to show this row?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, when starting '2019-07-01' and ending '2019-08-05', I have to take this rows as '2019-08-01' comes in it.

Comment: No effort made to solve this yourself? VTC needs focus.

Comment: @milken32 already solved his by myself. Need query solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **outer join**. You want to show all users with their dates in the given period, but still show the users when they don't have a date within.

```
select
  u.id,
  u.first_name,
  u.last_name,
  coalesce(rb.start_date, param.start_date) as start_date,
  coalesce(rb.end_date, param.end_date) as end_date,
  coalesce(rb.hours_per_day, 0) as hours_per_day
from (select date '2019-08-01' as start_date, date '2020-02-01' as end_date) param
cross join user u
left join resource_bookings rb on rb.user_id = u.id 
                              and rb.start_date <= param.end_date
                              and rb.end_date >= param.start_date
order by u.id, rb.id;
```

As you see, I am also using a cross join in my query in order to introduce the parameters once. This is not necessary, but otherwise you'd have to put the parameter dates multiple times in the query.

Comment: Your answer did not give sum of hours for period when two projects dates overlap and we did not get 0 for any period when we don't have record.

Comment: Please check the expected output section of question.

Comment: I see. You want to show all stored project periods plus fill all the gaps. Something you may prefer to do in your app rather than in SQL. If you *want* to do this in SQL, you will have to write a **recursive query**, I guess.

Comment: I did that using php logic and get my required result. But when users data becomes more than 5k, my logic becomes slow. This is reason why I want output using query.

Comment: It is unlikely that a solution in SQL will be faster. I'd rather expect it to be slower, because the process to fill the gaps will be about the same, but if you create the missing rows in SQL there will be more data to transfer.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten. What should I read to improve my sql logic and which is good resource for it? Please guide me about it.

Comment: Well, my answer was that it is unlikely that a SQL solution would help here. Anyway, if it's just about learning something new in SQL ... In order to fill gaps, you may want to iterate through the rows and use a recursive query. So, google "recursive query" for your DBMS. Another solution may be to combine two queries, one with existing data, one with created gap filling data with `UNION ALL`. You would probably use `LAG` or `LEAD` then to look into the previous or next row to detect a gap and create a row from this data. So, look for `LAG` and `LEAD` then. All this is available as of MySQL 8.

Comment: 1. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive 2. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Comment: You found a ‍♂️ !

Comment: @Thorsen thanks. I will read each chapter of dev.mysql.com to improve my sql.